# How to make page stay at the clicked tab in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Currently, the page is submitted after clicking tab-2 on the tab menu. However, page will go back to tab-1 after submitting. I would like page stay at tab-2 after clicking tab-2.

Is there anyone can help me? Many thanks!

Below is my code:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                $('#tabs-B').click(function() {
                    $('#target').submit();
                });

            });
    </script>



<div id="tabs">
    <form id="target">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tabs-B">Tab-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab-3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">


    </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a cookie before submitting to indicate what tab you last opened. then during page load, retrieve the cookie. if the cookie does not exist, by default you are in tab 1. otherwise, get the value of the cookie and open the tab as indicated by the cookie.

Comment: what you have said is to set cookie in php or Jquery? It will be really helpful if you can provide few code.

Comment: that would be in jQuery, or even plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie), you can use the 'cookie' [jQuery UI Tab](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) option.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```